# R: Unmatched brackets when there are none in Dplyr code

Tags: r, dplyr

```
FinalForecast<-FinalForecast%>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,toMillions)%>%
  bind_rows(summarise_all(., list(~if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total")))
```

When I use this line of code, the Bind Rows line gives an error.  The code still works and everything, but it gives me a warning in RStudio that there's an unmatched ')'.  I'm not sure if this is just something that RStudio is freaking out over, or if I've written something that's technically correct but bad form.

[image: what it looks like in my RStudio]

I wouldn't care if it was just me using the script, but I'm leaving my job, and wanted to leave some of these tools for some other folks, so I've been commenting up my code for people who are not exactly coders. I don't want them to worry about errors in the code, even if they still work.

Comment: Does the warning still show after saving the file? Rstudio sometimes does that, when there are unsaved changes to the file.

Comment: When I use local data, this code works fine, so I'll second @Till's suggestion. (I'm not using RStudio, though.)

Comment: That code is fine. I checked in my `RStudio` and it does not show the warning. Try to save the file and restart. On some operating systems that seem to happen every now and then.

Comment: Yeah, it still has the red, regardless of the saving

Comment: Oh, strange.  I had to restart my computer and it did end up working.  Thank you everyone.