# "Unmatched opening bracket" error in R when all the brackets look matched

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following function from the book "*Applied Multivariate
Statistics with R*" by Daniel Zelterman (page 365, at the bottom). The function is then used to create a bivariate plot.

```
corcon <- function(x, y, correl) {
  nx <- length(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  z <- matrix(rep(0, nx*ny), nx, ny)
  for (i in 1:nx) {
    for (j in 1:ny) {
      z[i, j] <- 
        dmvnorm(c(x[i], y[j]), c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, correl, correl, 1), 2, 2)
    }
  }
  return(z)
}
```

R Studio gives me three errors:

```
unmatched opening bracket '{'
unmatched opening bracket '('
unexpected closing bracket '{'
```

All the curly brackets look matched to me. I have tried saving the file and restarting R as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724814/r-unmatched-brackets-when-there-are-none-in-dplyr-code), but the error persists.

Comment: Your `dmvnorm()` isn't closed with a `)`.

Comment: Diagnosing such problems is easier if you use an editor that shows matching parentheses.  For example, in vim if you place the cursor on any parenthesis or brace bracket it highlights the matching one.

Comment: @jay.sf thanks a lot, it works now! What's the best way to find out what the issue is when R is throwing a bunch of errors? I was confused by the errors about the curly brackets, but those were fine.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you, R studio does the same actually. The problem is that R was throwing three errors in total, two about the curly brackets and one about tthe parenthesis, and I got fixated checking the curly brackets.

Comment: What version of R are you using?  When I run that code I don't get the error message reported in the question.  Using *R version 4.0.3 Patched (2020-12-21 r79672)* I get *Error: unexpected '}'* so it is not necessarily saying that it  is the brace bracket that is unbalanced but that message includes the possibility that a statement terminated prematurely.

Comment: I know these errors and they can be nasty especially with long functions. You could get into the habit of a more consistent style, e.g. something like [this](https://jef.works/R-style-guide/), then it's a little easier to see which bracket matches which and where there might be the mistake. I tried to show you in the edit.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I had Version 1.2.5033 for MacOs, now updated to Version 1.4.1106, but got the same types of error with the update. I guess you have the Windows version.

Comment: That is not an R version. Maybe that is an R Studio version?  If you enter `R.version.string` into R it shows the R version.  Maybe this discrepancy is due to R Studio?  If that is the case it seems strange that it would give worse error messages.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for the tip. I have now updated R to 4.0.4 (2021-02-15). I get the same error pattern as before, but I now see your point in the distinction between the "unmatched" error and "unexpected" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo in the published code - as @jay.sf found, `dmvnorm()` was not closed with a `)`.

I was unable to find the missing parenthesis myself because, given the three error messages:

```
unmatched opening bracket '{'
unmatched opening bracket '('
unexpected closing bracket '{'
```

- I overlooked the second error message, which was about a parenthesis and not a curly bracket
- Therefore, I checked the curly brackets only - and they were all matched.

Also, as @G.Grothendieck noted, the error `unexpected closing bracket '{'` "is not necessarily saying that it is the brace bracket that is unbalanced but that message includes the possibility that a statement terminated prematurely."

In addition to [better formatting](https://jef.works/R-style-guide/) as recommended by @jay.sf, **double-clicking in R Studio after a bracket or parenthesis highlights the section of the code between the matching brackets or parentheses** (something I did not know.) For example, going from the beginning of the code toward the end, we can check and see that the curly brackets are all matched:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But if I double-click on the parenthesis after `dvnorm`, only `c` is highlighted, showing that the parenthesis is not matched:

[image]

This is the fixed code:

```
corcon <- function(x, y, correl) {
  nx <- length(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  z <- matrix(rep(0, nx*ny), nx, ny)
  for (i in 1:nx) {
    for (j in 1:ny) {
      z[i, j] <- 
        dmvnorm(c(x[i], y[j]), c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, correl, correl, 1), 2, 2))
    }
  }
  return(z)
}
```